# How to display images as the same size in a V-Card

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

This should be a simple fix but I can’t figure it out. Please excuse my lack of posting my whole code.

Here is the issue. I am using the following

```
`
<v-card>
<v-img :src=“{{person.png}}”</v-img>
<v-card>
`
```

I have an array of users with profile images. Some of these images are different sizes ( some may be 400w other maybe 250w ). My issue is that because these images are different sizes, that they actually end up making my cards ( which are uniform in size ), different widths and height. This makes the cards ugly of course, and I need help on how to fix this.

Now, I had a friend build a react project, and I providing him with pictures, but the sizes were off. I fixed this by importing all images into Figma and making them all the same height and width, which, worked. However, for this project, this method isn’t working for me and I need a way to auto size these images so that my cards stay uniform.

I do not want to use the v-avatar feature, so please refrain from asking me, because these aren’t really “avatars”.

One “solution” I found was to use “contain” but I can’t find any information on contain in the documentation and I’m not sure if that would even work.

Comment: did you try to specify width and height like `<v-img :src="person.png" width="400" height="400"></v-img>`?

Comment: I sure did and what it did was actually force the size, but the images would be cropped, and even then it didn’t seem to work perfectly. Thank you for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a 1 size fits all fix for this, but this is what I did to make it work out.

```
1. I imported all images to figma
2. I edited the images to all be the same size, then used the crop tool to "fit" them to the new "canvas" size
3. Within my v-img , I added "contain", which insured that the picture didn't get cut off or cropped when placing inside of a card.

Thanks for the help all.
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in some edge cases you cannot depend only on the components provided by a framework and you need to improvise. This issue sounds purely like a CSS one. Instead of using vuetify component you could try to create own component and just apply the avatar image as element's background-image inline property. Then you could use **background-size: cover** in order to preserve correct ratio of uploaded images.

Comment: Seems odd that Vuetify wouldn’t allow something as simple as confirming an image inside of their components. Their documentation seems to have other, more complicated features.